Flutter code, truncate API and can't fetch full json data
Description
When i try to use the API from the call, the code truncate the api Json and the part of the json body that i use for conditionals to enable and disable view of widgets doesen't exist. I tried by checking the API but it gives back all the json data, i tried to make an example page, and the API this time is complete and in a text is not truncated. How can i fix this in my code?
The problem is not the API, but the code, that somehow saves half of the API and i can't use the part of the api that i need
Results
Expectation
{
  "10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f": {
    "b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b": {
      "titoloBanner": "Comune di Cagliari",
      "comuneFooter": "Comune di Cagliari",
      "urlLinkedIn": null,
      "codiceFiscaleFooter": "00147990923",
      "urlAssistenza": "https://www.comune.cagliari.it/portale/it/accedi_servizi.page?servizio=segnalazioni",
      "urlSegnalazioneDisservizi": null,
      "titoloHeader": "Sportello servizi Istruzione",
      "titoloHome": "Sportello Servizi Istruzione",
      "urlInformativaPrivacy": "https://www.comune.cagliari.it/portale/it/privacy.page",
      "logo": "logo_cagliari_trasparente (1).png;[PNG CODE]",
      "urlDichiarazioneAccessibilita": "https://form.agid.gov.it/view/32e1145b-80b3-4895-9a2c-5bf70b406ceb",
      "urlFAQ": null,
      "partitaIvaFooter": "00147990923",
      "urlFacebook": "https://www.facebook.com/comunecagliarinews.it",
      "urlYouTube": "https://www.youtube.com/user/ComuneCagliariNews",
      "urlWhatsApp": null,
      "descrizioneLogin": "",
      "titoloScheda": "",
      "sottotitoloHeader": null,
      "urlSitoIstituzionale": "https://www.comune.cagliari.it/portale/",
      "abilitaCIEID": "NO",
      "abilitaCNS": "NO",
      "urlTelegram": "https://telegram.me/comunecagliari",
      "provider": "config-portale",
      "coloreNavbar": "#003882",
      "urlTikTok": null,
      "pecFooter": "protocollogenerale@comune.cagliari.legalmail.it",
      "sottotitoloFooter": null,
      "authLevelCIEID": "2",
      "coloreBanner": "#003274",
      "authLevelSPID": "2",
      "urlPrenotazioneAppuntamenti": null,
      "indirizzoFooter": null,
      "abilitaSPID": "SI",
      "emailFooter": "",
      "titoloFooter": "Sportello servizi Istruzione",
      "coloreFooter": "#133370",
      "logoFooter": "logo_cagliari_trasparente (1).png;[PNG CODE]"
    }
  }
}

What i recieve back
{10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f: {b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b: {titoloBanner: Comune di Cagliari, comuneFooter: Comune di Cagliari, urlLinkedIn: null, codiceFiscaleFooter: 00147990923, urlAssistenza: https://www.comune.cagliari.it/portale/it/accedi_servizi.page?servizio=segnalazioni, urlSegnalazioneDisservizi: null, titoloHeader: Sportello servizi Istruzione, titoloHome: Sportello Servizi Istruzione, urlInformativaPrivacy: https://www.comune.cagliari.it/portale/it/privacy.page, logo: logo_cagliari_trasparente (1).png;[PNG CODE]"

Code
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/pages/widgetssss/a_u_t_hwidgets/cieid/cieid_widget.dart';
import '/pages/widgetssss/a_u_t_hwidgets/cns/cns_widget.dart';
import '/pages/widgetssss/a_u_t_hwidgets/credenziali/credenziali_widget.dart';
import '/pages/widgetssss/a_u_t_hwidgets/spid/spid_widget.dart';
import 'landing_page_model.dart';

class LandingPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LandingPageWidget> createState() => _LandingPageWidgetState();
}

class _LandingPageWidgetState extends State<LandingPageWidget> {
  late LandingPageModel _model;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => LandingPageModel());
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Fetch data da API
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://gateway.simeal-dev.maggioli.cloud/api/utilizzo-istanze/property-portale/dev'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Errore durante la chiamata API');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _model.unfocusNode.canRequestFocus
          ? FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_model.unfocusNode)
          : FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
        body: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primary,
                      Colors.white,
                    ],
                    stops: const [0.0, 1.0],
                    begin: const AlignmentDirectional(0.87, -1.0),
                    end: const AlignmentDirectional(-0.87, 1.0),
                  ),
                ),
                alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0.0, -1.0),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                          0.0,
                          70.0,
                          0.0,
                          32.0,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 200.0,
                          height: 70.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                          ),
                          alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'SiMeal',
                            style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                .displaySmall
                                .override(
                                  fontFamily: 'Titillium Web',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                            maxWidth: 570.0,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBackground,
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                blurRadius: 4.0,
                                color: Color(0x33000000),
                                offset: Offset(
                                  0.0,
                                  2.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              Align(
                                alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 0.0),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Inizia',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                            .displaySmall
                                            .override(
                                              fontFamily: 'Titillium Web',
                                              letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                            ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          0.0,
                                          12.0,
                                          0.0,
                                          24.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Per accedere seleziona il comune di appartenenza',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                              .labelLarge
                                              .override(
                                                fontFamily: 'Readex Pro',
                                                letterSpacing: 0.0,
                                              ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                        future: fetchData(),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                            return const Center(
                                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            );
                                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                            return Center(
                                              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                                            );
                                          } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                            return const Center(
                                              child: Text('No data available'),
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            final jsonData = snapshot.data!;

                                            final bool abilitaSPID =
                                                jsonData['abilitaSPID'] == 'SI';
                                            final bool abilitaCIEID =
                                                jsonData['abilitaCIEID'] == 'SI';
                                            final bool abilitaCNS =
                                                jsonData['abilitaCNS'] == 'SI';

                                            return Column(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                              children: [
                                                if (abilitaSPID)
                                                  wrapWithModel(
                                                    model: _model.spidModel,
                                                    updateCallback: () => setState(() {}),
                                                    child: const SpidWidget(),
                                                  ),
                                                if (abilitaCIEID)
                                                  wrapWithModel(
                                                    model: _model.cieidModel,
                                                    updateCallback: () => setState(() {}),
                                                    child: const CieidWidget(),
                                                  ),
                                                if (abilitaCNS)
                                                  wrapWithModel(
                                                    model: _model.cnsModel,
                                                    updateCallback: () => setState(() {}),
                                                    child: const CnsWidget(),
                                                  ),
                                                wrapWithModel(
                                                  model: _model.credenzialiModel,
                                                  updateCallback: () => setState(() {}),
                                                  child: const CredenzialiWidget(),
                                                ),
                                              ].divide(const SizedBox(height: 20.0)),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try to call fetchData() from initState() and save the returning Future to the State for further use. Never initiate anything heavy in build() as build() is intended to be called at every frame, possibly 60 times per second.

I tried to call the fetchData inside the initState, but still not working. The Api still being truncated

Your Response has inner maps, Try to access the key values using this method:
{
  "10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f" : {
    "b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b" : {
...
}
}
}

Update code
//Existing code

final bool abilitaSPID = jsonData['abilitaSPID'] == 'SI';
final bool abilitaCIEID = jsonData['abilitaCIEID'] == 'SI';
final bool abilitaCNS = jsonData['abilitaCNS'] == 'SI';
          
//Update with this code                              

final bool abilitaSPID = jsonData["10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f"]
                                            ["b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b"]
                                            ["abilitaSPID"] == 'SI';
final bool abilitaCIEID = jsonData["10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f"]
                                            ["b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b"]
                                            ["abilitaCIEID"] == 'SI';
final bool abilitaCNS = jsonData["10f6593b-20ac-4feb-85b3-4359084cb69f"]
                                            ["b996eedc-fcf8-4002-8b86-33a4be8b258b"]
                                            ["abilitaCNS"] == 'SI';

Directly reading a specific value from a map without knowing the key isn't possible in Dart. Maps are designed to associate specific keys with their corresponding values.
